# Are external HDD housed or custom built?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

The external HDD's are an HD housed or a custom built of an HD?

For example, if I open the external HD will I find a regular WD or Samsung driver or w/e or is it a more complicated version built specifically to run inside those boxes that you can't use outside of it with modifications?

Or how can I tell which external HDD can be taken apart for the HD it self?

Comment: Hi there,

Some external HDDs use just standard SATA internal HDDs inside, but others have different interfaces like the WD My Passport that has the USB interface attached directly to  the PCB. Some units also have hardware encryption and if any data is stored on them while they are still in the enclosure cannot be read once they are removed from it. In general it depends from the particular model and manufacturer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It depends".

Your mileage may vary but *typically* "powered" drive enclosures tend to have 3.5 inch desktop drives identical to the one you find in your PC (and you may in many cases, simply swap them out in the case). Some companies used to buy these and 'shuck' them for the drives during the bad hard drive shortages of the past.

2.5 inch 'self powered' drives vary. The generic ones and *many* of the ones you can buy off the shelf are regular 2.5 inch drives but at least one major brand (WD passport) has a special circuit board with USB built in and no obvious SATA connectors. I'm not sure about the other major brands.

See picture below, proprietary WD drive on left, standard Sata drive on right.

[image]

To be safe, in those cases, you'd probably want to google the model you're looking at to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, how can I check that for example [in this one](http://www.amazon.com/Seagate-Expansion-Desktop-External-STBV3000100/dp/B00834SJU8) I can see it offers USB connection, but I cant see to know how to define whether it is or not

Comment: You can definitely take one of those apart to get at the hard drive. The time I tried it on an older version, it was a serious pain, but those things do have a normal HDD inside.

Comment: Thanks Journeyman, I have some points left that is just enough to get 2 of those but I wanted to use it on my NAS hence why I was wondering if I could take it apart.

Comment: Nice update, wish I could up vote once more xD